# To produce an random output: 100 numbers from 901 to 999

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to create two separate outputs of 10 columns and 10 rows of numbers. I know I can do the first output using numbers 4 through 7 and the second output using numbers 10 through 90. But I have in trouble to do the third output using numbers 901 through 999. Below is the Java code I have:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class LabRandom
{

private static final Random rand = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int number;

    int i = 1;

    while (i <= 100)
    {
        //number = rand.nextInt(4) + 4;
        System.out.printf("%-5d", rand.nextInt(4) + 4);

        if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println();

    i = 1; 

    while (i <= 100)
    {
        //number = rand.nextInt(4) + 4;
        System.out.printf("%-5d", rand.nextInt(9)*10+10);

        if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println();

    i = 1;

     while (i <= 100)
    {
        //number = rand.nextInt(4) + 4;
        System.out.printf("%-5d", rand.nextInt(100)*10);

        if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        i++;
    }

   }    
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If your want 901 to 999 then your nextInt should be for 99, not 100.  (And, of course, you need to add 901 and **not** multiply by 10.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble understanding what you want. If you want to create an output of 100 randomly chosen number in the range 900 to 999, with line breaks after every 10 such numbers, try adding this loop to your code:

```
i = 1;
while (i <= 100) 
{
    // generate a random number from 0 to 100-1,
    // then add 900 to transform the range to 900 to 999
    System.out.printf("%-5d", rand.nextInt(100) + 900);

    if (i % 10 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you really want to print numbers 10 to 90, your second loop is incorrect.
Right now you print multiples of 10, from 10 to 90, eg 10,20,30.....90

For every number between, you would want:
rand.nextInt(80)+10

Answer (score 0):

```
        // difference between the highest and the lowest value you want to have in your result
        int range = 99;
        // the lowest possible value you want to see in your result
        int lowestValue = 901;
        //note that you will never get the numbers 900 and 1000 this way, only between
        int result = rand.nextInt(range) + lowestValue;
```

You might want to read what exactly nextInt(value) does (easy to do inside a proper IDE since it will provide JavaDoc tooltip, which is of course available and well detailed in such general Java classes).